# Can I use generic constraints to enable a parameterized constructor?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a function like so:

```
public List<T> SelectAll<T>() where T : DatabaseObject, new()
{
    List<T> retVal = new List<T>();
    String command = "Select * from " + GetType().Name;
    MySqlCommand cmd = DatabaseRunner.GetCommand(command);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        T newObj = new T(reader);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

You can see when I try to create a new `T` object, I pass in a `MySqlDataReader` object to the constructor. How can I modify the method signature to allow this?

Comment: You can cheat, let T implement an interface containing a single factory method which creates a new T and takes an argument. Kind of ugly, but it beats reflection IMO.

Answer (score 9):

You cannot. C# only supports the `new()` constraint (which you're already using) for constraining the type parameter to types with a parameterless constructor. Constructors with parameters are not supported in this context.

Comment: I would suggest instead what you want is an interface that has a parameter which takes a `SqlDataReader` and reads (and initializes) the object as necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Short answer is you can't. One way around this is to remove the new() constraint and use [Activator.CreateInstance()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx):

```
T value = (T) Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), reader)
```

Comment: Remember to cast the result to `T`.

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this with a constraint. However, you can call the method and pass in a function to create a `T` from a `MySqlDataReader`:

```
public List<T> SelectAll<T>(Func<MySqlDataReader, T> projection)
    where T : DatabaseObject
{
    List<T> retVal = new List<T>();
    String command = "Select * from " + GetType().Name;
    MySqlCommand cmd = DatabaseRunner.GetCommand(command);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        retValue.Add(projection(reader));
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

(You may well want to use `DbDataReader` instead of `MySqlDataReader` to avoid being so specific.)

Another alternative is to give `DatabaseObject` something like an `Initialize(DbDataReader reader)` method, then you could use:

```
public List<T> SelectAll<T>() where T : DatabaseObject, new()
{
    List<T> retVal = new List<T>();
    String command = "Select * from " + GetType().Name;
    MySqlCommand cmd = DatabaseRunner.GetCommand(command);
    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        T value = new T();
        value.Initialize(reader);
        retValue.Add(value);
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

As a side issue, you're not disposing of anything - you should really be using `using` statements to dispose of the reader and the command automatically.

Comment: I just finished writing IDENTICAL code a second ago!  Good answer :)