# Instantiate new object based on type parameter

Tags: c#, type-parameter

I am trying to throw an exception based on the exception type parameter passed to the method.

Here is what I have so far but I don't want to specify each kind of exception:

```
public void ThrowException<T>(string message = "") where T : SystemException, new()
    {
        if (ConditionMet)
        {
            if(typeof(T) is NullReferenceException)
                throw new NullReferenceException(message);

            if (typeof(T) is FileNotFoundException)
                throw new FileNotFoundException(message);

            throw new SystemException(message);
        }
    }
```

Ideally I want to do something like `new T(message)` given I have a base type of `SystemException` I would have thought this was somehow possible.

Comment: Cannot be done, but there are workarounds. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772414/can-i-use-generic-constraints-to-enable-a-parameterized-constructor/7772426#7772426

Comment: Also, be aware that it is not good practice to throw exceptions such as NullReferenceException in user code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think that you can do this using gerics alone. You would need to use reflection. Something like:

```
throw (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),message);
```

Comment: Remember to cast to `T` or `Exception` since you can't throw an `object`

Comment: I would also recommend you add an explicit check that the type supports the expected constructor and throw a meaningful exception if the check fails.

Answer (score 1):

As others stated, this can only be done with reflection. But you could drop the type parameter and pass the instantiated exception to the function:

```
public void ThrowException(Exception e)
{
    if (ConditionMet)
    {
        if(e is NullReferenceException || e is FileNotFoundException)
        {
            throw e;
        }

        throw new SystemException(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
// throws a NullReferenceException
ThrowException(new NullReferenceException("message"));
// throws a SystemException
ThrowException(new NotSupportedException("message"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T),message);
```

More at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d.aspx